# Update a file inside zip with -u

Tags: linux, zip

Alright so i have a zip file called data.zip on my desktop. Inside test.zip is another folder called res and inside res is a file called info.txt
I have used the zip -u command before to move a file inside the zip but only to the root of the zip i want to move a new version of info.txt from my desktop to the res folder of data.zip i need it for part of a script i'm working on. How can i do this or will the -u function only work for the root?
Thank you for any help on how i can accomplish this

Answer (score 2):

Use the `-j` option (*j*unk the pathname) if you want to target the root of the zip; in order to target a subdirectory, you'll need to arrange your current directory such that the relative path from it to the file matches the relative path inside the zipfile.  Something like this:

```
mkdir res
cp $DESKTOP/info.txt res
zip -u data.zip res/info.txt
rm -rf res
```

Comment: Worked perfectly thanks a ton didn't think to put the info.txt in a res folder on my desktop